# How to append the multiple values from resultset?

Tags: java

I have resultset with below data for one product code same like more productcodes. Now i want to get only itemcode and desc in single row as string in java. How to get these values ? I knew if going to get through SQL , its very simple.but i don't want to hit database again.I would like to use same resultset. Please advise.

```
product   itemcode  Desc
6799        8205        OR
6799        8206        OR
6799        8208        OR
6799        8422        OR
6799        8424        OR
6799        1381        OR
6799        1485        OR
6799        1563        OR
```

Expected output:

```
 column1  column2  column3  
6799      item1   8205 OR 8206 OR 8208 OR8422 
6799      item2   8205 OR 8206 OR 8208 OR8422 
6799      item3   8205 OR 8206 OR 8208 OR8422 
6799      item4   8205 OR 8206 OR 8208 OR8422 
6799      item5   8205 OR 8206 OR 8208 OR8422
```

Comment: What you are getting and what is your expected output should be.. I think you can make use of `Stringbuilder` while iterating through resultset.. [Class StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: Expected output is : 8205 OR 8206 OR 8208 OR8422 OR as like...

Comment: Yes, your correct. Already i'm getting many values using iterator so once get the productcode , i can pass to another function to achive these values. but how to implement another function here ?

Comment: You need to show the code and what querie you are running. I have one pseudo code for StringBuilder. If you want that let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String product = rs.getString("product");
        String itemCode = rs.getString("itemcode");
        String desc = rs.getString("Desc");
        String mapValue = "";
        if (resultMap.containsKey(product)) {
            mapValue = resultMap.get(product) + " " + itemCode + " " + desc ;
        }
        resultMap.put(product, mapValue);
    }

    int itemCount = 1;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "  item" + itemCount + " " + entry.getValue());
        itemCount++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So what is stopping you to fetch your desired column values and getting them clubbed in a single string, as mentioned here:

```
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String itemCode = rs.getString("itemcode");
            String desc = rs.getString("Desc");
            System.out.println(itemCode + " " + desc);
          }
```

Comment: column1 : 6799 6799  6799  6799  6799

Comment: What output you have got after using my sample. and what output do u desire?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate over a ResultSet again.  If you look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) for that class, you'll note that it has "a cursor that moves forward only."  This means that, if you need to do multiple things with a data point, you need to either store the result set in another data structure (in memory), which can be very expensive, or you need to do multiple things as you iterate over it.

The easiest thing to do in this case is to instantiate a StringBuilder and append to it as you go:

```
StringBuilder sb = new Stringbuilder();
boolean first = true;

while (row) {
    // other code
    if (!first) {
      sb.append(" OR " + row[2]);
      first = false;
    } else {
      sb.append(row[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case, the code becomes simpler. Eliminate `first` and simply append both columns to the `StringBuilder`.